# Custom UITableView Cell with UIButton not Calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I understand this is suppose to happen but I haven't been able to find a way to call this method when the button is tapped The method gets called but the wrong cell is selected.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object{
_postCell = (postCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"postCell"];
_postCell.personStringPost.text = [object objectForKey:@"stringPost"];
[_postCell.nameLabel setTitle:[object objectForKey:@"User_Name"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_postCell.userId = [object objectForKey:@"userId"];
_postCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"profileImage"];
NSData *data = [imageFile getData];
_postCell.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

[_postCell.nameLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(personProfile:tableView:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_postCell.profileImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(personProfile:tableView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return _postCell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
postCell *cell = (postCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
self.userId = cell.userId;
NSLog(@"Did Select: %@", self.userId);
}

- (void) personProfile: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath tableView: (UITableView *) tableView{
[self tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"personProfile" sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things i hope it will help

while dealing with button with only one section

in cellfor row method

```
yourcell.mybutton.tag=indexPath.row;

-(void)myCellbuttonAction:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; // first, cast the sender to UIButton
  NSInteger row = button.tag; // recover the row
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];

  // apply your logic for indexpath  as in didselect row   
}
```

While dealing with multiple sections and multiple rows it this might help you

in cell for row method

```
yourcell.tag=indexPath.section;
yourcell.contentview.tag=indexPath.row;
```

and your button action might look like this

```
-(void)myCellbuttonAction:(id)sender
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; // first, cast the sender to UIButton

id rowid =[button superview];
id sectionid = [rwoid superview];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[rowid tag] inSection:[sectionid tag]];

 // apply your logic for indexpath  as in didselect row   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things here.

a) I would not use an instance variable (_postCell) in your cellForRowAtIndex method.  You will likely have cell re-use problems and this may well be the source of your error.  Replace it with a local variable:

```
postcell *cell = (postCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"postCell"];
```

You will also need to replace all references to `_postCell` with `cell`.

b) Note that in the same line your cast uses lowercase `= (postCell *)...` - I have done the same above, but it is best practice for class names to start with capital letters.

c) You have a property named `nameLabel`, which suggests its a `UILabel`, but you are using the `setTitle:forState:` method, which implies it's a `UIButton`.   I would rename this property since debugging will be a lot easier if the names match the classes (or at least don't imply the wrong class).

d) When you call the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents` method, your selector is for `personProfile:tableView:`.   The signature for that method is for an NSIndexPath and a UITableView.  But your button will not be sending those arguments of those types.  It will send details of the sender - i.e. the button which triggered the action.  So you need to revise your method to accept arguments of that type:

```
[cell.nameLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

e) When the method gets called, you need a way to determine which cell the sending button was on.  Ideally you would subclass UIButton to add some link to the cell, but (if you have only one section) you might get away with putting the row number as a tag.  To do this add:

```
cell.nameLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
```

to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  Then you can implement a different method to handle the button press, as follows:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; // first, cast the sender to UIButton
    NSInteger row = button.tag; // recover the row
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]; // derive the indexPath, assuming section is 0
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; // select the relevant row in the table (assuming the table is self.tableView)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"personProfile" sender:self]; // perform the segue
}
```

f) Note in the above that you should not **call** `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.  This is for the tableView to call when the user selects the row, not for selecting rows programmatically.  Use `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` instead.

Comment: That didn't work. No error message, just didn't work

Comment: Exactly what doesn't work?  Is the wrong cell selected?  Is no cell selected?  Does `didSelectRowAtIndex` get called?  Put some NSLogs in: Does `buttonPressed:` get called?  Does it use the right indexPath in `selectRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically pbasdf answer above with **Swift 3**

I do call **didSelectRowAt** directly since it is not triggered by **selectRowAtIndexPath**

The tag is set on cell creation with the row of the indexpath

The **getTableView** function is my own

```
@IBAction func actionButtonPushed(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }
    guard let tableView = getTableView() else { return }
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: button.tag, section: 0)
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    if let delegate = tableView.delegate {
      delegate.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
    }
}
```