# Button action over didselectrowatindexpath

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I have added a container view into cell. But when i try to click button inside the View only delegate method **didselectrowatindexpath** is called

[image]

How to handle the button click before **didselectrowatindexpath** ?

Comment: Maybe helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206490/custom-uitableview-cell-with-uibutton-not-calling-didselectrowatindexpath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add target method to the button as shown below

```
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Add button click method as below

```
-(void)btnclick:(UIButton *)sender
{
    int index = sender.tag;

}
```

Comment: Make sure that the area button covers is large enough so that user can easily click the button

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue, i have height of cell < container view heigh. Need expand cell height and all work fine!